# How can I track file in folder already found in .gitignore

Tags: php, git, github

In file .gitignore there are folder name item....Now I want to track only one file  and ignore the reset of the folder.
and this is the content of my .gitignore

panel
photo
item/*
!item/default.png
jackbox
profile_photo
vid
.htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Use negate pattern in `.gitignore` file:

```
item/*
!item/default.png
```

Just edit `.gitignore` and commit it.

[Manual page for gitignore](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html)

Comment: Expanded answer, use this in .gitignore file.

Comment: @Ahmedel-Gendy there is no command -- it's as Kacer said: you edit your .gitignore file (using whatever editor you use).

Comment: when I edit .gitignore i write !item/default.png the result that trace folder item .... I only want to trace default.png not the whole folder

Comment: @Ahmedel-Gendy So put the full path to the file into the git ignore.

Comment: @Ahmedel-Gendy Please add content of your `.gitignore`, to your question.

Comment: @Kacer this is content of .gitignore 
hotel
images
item/*
!item/default.png
jackbox
panel
photo